# Bootstrap button: left icon and centered text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I need to generate a button (not a group of buttons) with the following structure:

left-side: [glyphicon]
center: Text

example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3idura8mxf4gekj/call_me.png

Here is what I did:

```
<div class="row btn-custom">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg col-xs-12" >
          <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></button>
          <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-10">Call Us</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-1"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.btn-custom {
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

.btn-custom button { 
    border-left:none; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

The problem that on a very small screen they start to stack up and don't look like one button. is there any better way to achieve this?

- this code is intended to be used only on a mobile site (m.* url) so please do not recommend me to do other stuff, i know what i am doing.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use a simple button, with `.pull-left` on your glyphe :

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-xs-12">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone pull-left"></span> Call Us
</button>
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/101546)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-large"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> Call us</button>
```

On your approach there are three buttons thats why it is stacked on mobile

Comment: that's not what i want. i want the icon to be in the left and the call us in the middle, and the button is full width (col-xs-12)